# Add node to xmltype variable

Tags: xml, plsql, xmltype

in a clob column i store xml files then i select one record and i load data of the clob column in an XMLType variable.

My question is, is it possible to modify the XMLType variable by adding a new node ? I don't want to modify the clob, just manipulate the XML loaded in the XMLType variable.

Then, i want give to each new node a sequence number

I've trying this

```
update int_tmp_imp
set xml_file = APPENDCHILDXML(XMLType(xml_file), '/Supplier/Vendor',
  XMLType('<XMLID>'||S_test.NEXTVAL||'</XMLID>')).getclobval() where id_file = 484;
```

But it modify my clob column and the value of the new tag is the same for each new node.

Is it possible to do this and how ?

Thx a lot.